# CrossStorageClient fails with timeout

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, local-storage

I have a site with subdomains and I need to exchange data between them.
For instance I enter on the site: www.example.com, login and now I'm on the mydomain.example.com.
My site uses angularjs, so I decided to use this [lib](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage)
I successfully added it to my project and I see that all needfull iframes are initated. But when I'm trying to get or set a key I get a timeout error:

> client.js:410 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Timeout: could not perform cross-storage:set

Here's my code:

```
CrossStorageHub.init([
    { origin: /\w\.example.com$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del'] },
    { origin: /example.com$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del'] },
    { origin: 'www.example.com', allow: ['get', 'set', 'del'] },
    { origin: 'http://example.com/', allow: ['get', 'set', 'del'] }
]);
const client = new CrossStorageClient('http://example.com', {
    timeout: 5000,
    frameId: 'storageFrame'
});
client.onConnect().then(() => {
    client.set('newKey', 'foobar', 90000);
});
```

Any pieces of advice would be helpful.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I get the same vague error and no pointers to a potential cause.